# Format a number as currency in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a query that returns a decimal value.  I'm looking for a way to format the value as currency.  My current use case is limited to USD, but I'm sure others are looking for similar solutions.

I'd like to be able to go from "123456.789" to "$123,456.79".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a currency data type in Azure Data Explorer. This generates the value you're describing but it ends up as a string which probably isn't what you want.

```
print Value=123456.789
| extend Currency = round(Value, 2)
| extend Decimal = round(Currency % 1, 2)
| extend WholeNumber = toint(Currency)
| extend Segment4 = WholeNumber / 1000000000 % 1000
| extend Segment3 = WholeNumber / 1000000 % 1000
| extend Segment2 = WholeNumber / 1000 % 1000
| extend Segment1 = WholeNumber % 1000
| project CurrencyString = 
    strcat(
        '$',
        iff(Segment4 > 0, strcat(tostring(Segment4), ','), ''),
        iff(Segment3 > 0, strcat(tostring(Segment3), ','), ''),
        iff(Segment2 > 0, strcat(tostring(Segment2), ','), ''),
        iff(Segment1 > 0, tostring(Segment1), ''),
        substring(Decimal, 1))
```

The team takes feature requests at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer

[Updated to handle commas for numbers ... but still has plenty of flaws/limitations.]

Comment: That's very close, but there is no comma.  I was hoping to be able to avoid a complex function to evaluate the magnitude of the number and assemble the string, or a regular expression.

Comment: Yeah I think the real answer is that there isn't support for it. You can request it but generally converting to currency would be something you'd do in your reporting/client software, not in ADX itself. I updated my answer with a start of the "complex function" you were talking about mostly just for fun.

Comment: I accepted the new answer as it does what I asked :)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a function to help with this:

```
let currencyFormat = (number: real, symbol: string = "", separator: string = " ") {
    //Convert number to string with 2 decimal places. 
    let StringNum = tostring(round(number, 2));
    //Get the index of the .
    let indexOfDot = indexof(StringNum, ".");
    //Get the number without decimals
    let Num = iif(indexOfDot > -1, substring(StringNum, 0, indexOfDot), StringNum);
    //Get the decimal without number (includes .)
    let Decimal = iif(indexOfDot > -1, substring(StringNum, indexOfDot), "");
    //If decimal only has 1 character, add a 0 afterwards.
    let DecimalFinal = iif(strlen(Decimal) == 2, strcat(Decimal, "0"), Decimal);
    //Get the length of the Number part
    let len = strlen(Num);
    //Get the segments divided into 1000s
    let seg1 = iif(len >= 3, substring(Num, len - 3, 3), Num);
    let seg2 = iif(len >= 6, substring(Num, len - 6, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 3));
    let seg3 = iif(len >= 9, substring(Num, len - 9, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 6));
    let seg4 = iif(len >= 12, substring(Num, len - 12, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 9));
    let seg5 = iif(len >= 15, substring(Num, len - 15, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 12));
    //Output the final value
    strcat(
        symbol,
        iif(strlen(seg5) > 0, strcat(seg5, separator), ""),
        iif(strlen(seg4) > 0, strcat(seg4, separator), ""),
        iif(strlen(seg3) > 0, strcat(seg3, separator), ""),
        iif(strlen(seg2) > 0, strcat(seg2, separator), ""),
        seg1,
        DecimalFinal
    )
};
```

Use it like so:

```
let currencyFormat = (number: real, symbol: string = "", separator: string = " ") { 
    let StringNum = tostring(round(number, 2));
    let indexOfDot = indexof(StringNum, ".");
    let Num = iif(indexOfDot > -1, substring(StringNum, 0, indexOfDot), StringNum);
    let Decimal = iif(indexOfDot > -1, substring(StringNum, indexOfDot), "");
    let DecimalFinal = iif(strlen(Decimal) == 2, strcat(Decimal, "0"), Decimal);
    let len = strlen(Num);
    let seg1 = iif(len >= 3, substring(Num, len - 3, 3), Num);
    let seg2 = iif(len >= 6, substring(Num, len - 6, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 3));
    let seg3 = iif(len >= 9, substring(Num, len - 9, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 6));
    let seg4 = iif(len >= 12, substring(Num, len - 12, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 9));
    let seg5 = iif(len >= 15, substring(Num, len - 15, 3), substring(Num, 0, len - 12));
    strcat(
        symbol,
        iif(strlen(seg5) > 0, strcat(seg5, separator), ""),
        iif(strlen(seg4) > 0, strcat(seg4, separator), ""),
        iif(strlen(seg3) > 0, strcat(seg3, separator), ""),
        iif(strlen(seg2) > 0, strcat(seg2, separator), ""),
        seg1,
        DecimalFinal
    )
};
MySource
| where Currency1 > 0
| project Currency1 = currencyFormat(Currency1, "$", ","),
          Currency2 = currencyFormat(Currency2, "R", ","),
          Currency3 = currencyFormat(Currency3)
```

**INPUT:**

```
Currency1 = 1254.3
Currency2 = 13231.02
Currency3 = 4213
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Currency1 | Currency2  | Currency3
-----------|------------|-----------
 $1,254.30 | R13,231.02 | 4 213.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation.  Supports negative amounts ( $-123.45 ) and always two digits for cents ( $123.00 )

```
let ToFormattedCurrency = (value:decimal ) 
{
    let DecimalString = tostring( round( value, 2 ) );
    let Sign = iff( DecimalString startswith "-", "-","");
    let DollarsString = substring( DecimalString, 0, indexof(DecimalString, "." ) );
    let CentsString = strcat(substring(DecimalString, indexof(DecimalString, "." )), "00"); //pad with extra 00 to force 2 digits, will remove later
    let AbsDollarsString = iff( DollarsString startswith "-", substring(DollarsString,1),DollarsString);
    let AbsDollarsReversedString = reverse(AbsDollarsString);
    let AbsDollarsReversedStringLen = strlen(AbsDollarsReversedString);
    let _hundreds = substring( AbsDollarsReversedString, 0, 3 );
    let _thoundsands = iff( AbsDollarsReversedStringLen > 3,  strcat( _hundreds, ",", substring( AbsDollarsReversedString, 3, 3 ) ), _hundreds );
    let _millions = iff( AbsDollarsReversedStringLen > 6,  strcat( _thoundsands, ",", substring( AbsDollarsReversedString, 6, 3 ) ), _thoundsands ); 
    let _billions = iff( AbsDollarsReversedStringLen > 9,  strcat( _millions, ",", substring( AbsDollarsReversedString, 9, 3 ) ), _millions );
    let FormattedDollarReverse = iff( AbsDollarsReversedStringLen > 12,  strcat( _billions, ",", substring( AbsDollarsReversedString, 12, 3 ) ), _billions );
    strcat("$",Sign,reverse(FormattedDollarReverse), substring( CentsString, indexof( CentsString,".", 0), 3) )
};
```